# Cocos2d-x using compiled lua script doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, c++, lua, cocos2d-x

I've been trying to make the HelloLua example to work in Android. It works if the hello.lua is not in compiled form using luac. But if I compile the hello.lua and upload it in my Android phone, it just gives me a black screen. Can anyone help me out in this?

This is the code in the AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()

```
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    CCString* pstrFileContent = CCString::createWithContentsOfFile("hello.lua");
    if (pstrFileContent)
    {
        pEngine->executeString(pstrFileContent->getCString());
    }
#else
    std::string path = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathForFilename("hello.lua");
    pEngine->addSearchPath(path.substr(0, path.find_last_of("/")).c_str());
    pEngine->executeScriptFile(path_c_str());
#endif
```

Seems that compiled lua works when I'm running in Windows but not in Android.

Answer (score 2):

The [man page](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/luac.html) for `luac` says that "Precompiled chunks are not portable across different architectures".